# JQuery.Post throwing error when calling WCF service

Tags: jquery

I've written a WCF service which takes a string and returns a string. When I call it from my javascript, it causes the error alert to be displayed.

I've tried reading the API and unsure of what I'm doing wrong or how to display the actual error message.

Here is my javascript:

```
var path = "http://localhost:15286/Service.svc/SubmitTest?url=" + encodeURIComponent(info.srcUrl);
var jqxhr = $.post(path, function() {

  alert("success");
})
.success(function() { alert("second success"); })
.error(function(oEvent) { alert("error"); })
.complete(function() { alert("complete"); });
};
```

I've watched the service through the debugger when it is called and it is returning the string "Hello World" without error so I assume my problem is on the javascript side.

WCF Service:

```
 [ServiceContract]
public interface IService
{
    [WebInvoke(UriTemplate = "/Submit?input={value}")]
    [OperationContract]
    string Submit(string value);
}

public class Service : IService
{
    public string Submit(string input)
    {
      return "hello world";
}
```

Comment: What response content type is the service setting?

Comment: Sorry @gdoron, I do not understand your question :(

Answer (score 0):

Use the dataType parameter, if the service returns "Hello World" then the dataType is "text":

```
var jqxhr = $.post(path, function() {

  alert("success");
}, "text") // <====
.success(function() { alert("second success"); })
.error(function(oEvent) { alert("error"); })
.complete(function() { alert("complete"); });
};
```

> dataTypeThe type of data expected from the server. Default: Intelligent Guess (xml, json, script, text, html).

And many times the guess isn't too "Intelligent"...

Answer (score 0):

you might be facing the cross domain issues try adding the

```
Headers.Add("Access-Control-Allow-Origin", "*");
```

say in the service the response looks like

```
var Response = new HttpResponseMessage<string>("hello world");
Response.Headers.Add("Access-Control-Allow-Origin", "*");
return Response ;
```

Comment: Sorry, are you suggesting I add this to the service or javascript?

Comment: i should be more clear, add the access control header to the service response

Comment: Sorry, I've updated my question to include the code from my service. I'm literally just returning a string from my function. I'm not sure where I should be returning the response you mentioned (I'm very new to WCF services, this is my first one)

Comment: Sorry, I tried this but I couldn't get the HttpResponseMessage type to be recognised. I tried including System.Net but that didn't do the job.

I tried making the function return void instead of string and the javascript still fell into the error block so I'm not sure the problem is on the service end.